# Getting compile time error while deploying application in IBM Integration Toolkit 10

Tags: esb, soa, ibm-integration-bus

I am getting below error while deploying my application on EG exist on remote integration node.

> BIP2087E: Integration node 'IIB10Node' was unable to process the
> internal configuration message.
>
> The entire internal configuration message failed to be processed
> successfully.
>
> Use the messages following this message to determine the reasons for
> the failure. If the problem cannot be resolved after reviewing these
> messages, contact your IBM Support center. Enabling service trace may
> help determine the cause of the failure.
>
> BIP4041E: Integration server 'EGTesting' received an administration
> request that encountered an exception.
>
> While attempting to process an administration request, an exception
> was encountered. No updates have been made to the configuration of the
> integration server.
>
> Review related error messages to determine why the administration
> request failed.
>
> BIP2401E: (com.esql.code.UAE_FTProcess_Transaction.Main, 51.47) :
> Syntax error : expected '=' but found '.'.
>
> The expected token was not found.
>
> Correct the syntax of your ESQL expression in node
> 'com.esql.code.UAE_FTProcess_Transaction.Main', around line and column
> '51.47', then redeploy the message flow.
>
> BIP2871I: The request made by user 'iibadmin[Default]' to 'deploy' the
> resource
> 'C:/Users/905293/IBM/IIBT10/Adil_workspace/GeneratedBarFiles/AsyncUAE_FTAppproject.generated.bar'
> of type 'BAR' on parent 'EGTesting' of type 'ExecutionGroup' has the
> status of 'FAILED'.

Below is my esql code where this compilation error mention line number and file name. My code is mostly commented and no semantic error are showing. I've clean my project and change my workspace several time and deploy but getting same error every time. The line where my error occur on esql are commented still it showing this. I cannot understand this what i could do now. Kindly help.

```
CREATE COMPUTE MODULE UAE_FTProcess_Transaction
    CREATE FUNCTION Main() RETURNS BOOLEAN
    BEGIN

        DECLARE Schemas CHARACTER 'IIBUAT';
        DECLARE Table CHARACTER 'ft_transaction';
        DECLARE HEADER_IN CHARACTER '';
        DECLARE TRAN_DETAIL CHARACTER '';
        DECLARE DR_INFO CHARACTER '';
        DECLARE CR_INFO CHARACTER '';
        DECLARE SC_DETAIL CHARACTER '';
        DECLARE REV_DETAIL CHARACTER '';
        DECLARE META_DATA CHARACTER '';
        DECLARE XML_REQ CHARACTER '';
        DECLARE XML_RESP CHARACTER '';

        DECLARE i INT 1;
        SET Environment.Variables.FTData[]= SELECT * FROM Database.{Schemas}.{Table} AS A WHERE
        A.TRANSACTION_STATUS='N' AND A.TRANSACTION_COUNT=1;     


        DECLARE ft_data REFERENCE TO Environment.Variables;
        WHILE(i<=CARDINALITY(ft_data.FTData[])) DO

        DECLARE ft_seq REFERENCE TO ft_data.FTData[i];

    --  SET HEADER_IN=
    --  '<HEADER_IN><CORR_ID>DAPP888260726808</CORR_ID><USER_NAME>CBS</USER_NAME><CHANNEL>DAPP</CHANNEL><APPLICATION>GNBAQRG</APPLICATION><WORK_STATION>Kci-DigAppBack</WORK_STATION><AUTH_KEY></AUTH_KEY></HEADER_IN>';

    --  SET TRAN_DETAIL=
    --  '<MSG_TYPE>O</MSG_TYPE><STAN>'||ft_seq.STAN||'</STAN><TRAN_DATETIME>'||ft_seq.TRAN_DATETIME||'</TRAN_DATETIME><TRAN_AMT>'||ft_seq.TRAN_AMT||'</TRAN_AMT><TRAN_DESC>'||ft_seq.TRAN_DESC||'</TRAN_DESC><CHEQUE_NO></CHEQUE_NO><CCY_RATE/>';

    --  SET DR_INFO=
    --  '<DR_INFO><DR_BANK_CODE>'||ft_seq.DR_BANK_CODE||'</DR_BANK_CODE><DR_BANK_NAME>'||ft_seq.DR_BANK_NAME||'</DR_BANK_NAME><DR_ACCT_TITLE>'||ft_seq.DR_ACCT_TITLE||'</DR_ACCT_TITLE><DR_ACCT_IBAN>'||ft_seq.DR_ACCT_IBAN||'</DR_ACCT_IBAN><DR_ACCT_TYPE>'||ft_seq.DR_ACCT_TYPE||'</DR_ACCT_TYPE><DR_ACCT_NO>'||ft_seq.DR_ACCT_NO||'</DR_ACCT_NO><DR_BRANCH>'||ft_seq.DR_BRANCH||'</DR_BRANCH><DR_CCY>'||ft_seq.DR_CCY||'</DR_CCY><DR_CLIENT_NO>'||ft_seq.DR_CLIENT_NO||'</DR_CLIENT_NO><DR_CRC>PKR</DR_CRC><DR_VALUE_DATE>'||ft_seq.DR_VALUE_DATE||'</DR_VALUE_DATE></DR_INFO>';
    
        --SET CR_INFO=
        --'<CR_INFO><CR_BANK_CODE>'||ft_seq.CR_BANK_CODE||'</CR_BANK_CODE><CR_BANK_NAME>'||ft_seq.CR_BANK_NAME||'</CR_BANK_NAME><CR_ACCT_TITLE>'||ft_seq.CR_ACCT_TITLE||'</CR_ACCT_TITLE><CR_ACCT_TYPE>'||ft_seq.CR_ACCT_TYPE||'</CR_ACCT_TYPE><CR_ACCT_NO>'||ft_seq.CR_ACCT_NO||'</CR_ACCT_NO><CR_BRANCH>'||ft_seq.CR_BRANCH||'</CR_BRANCH><CR_CCY>'||ft_seq.CR_CCY||'</CR_CCY><CR_CLIENT_NO>'||ft_seq.CR_CLIENT_NO||'</CR_CLIENT_NO><CR_CRC>PKR</CR_CRC><CR_VALUE_DATE>'||ft_seq.CR_VALUE_DATE||'</CR_VALUE_DATE></CR_INFO>';

        SET SC_DETAIL='<SC_DETAIL><ORIG_TRAN_REF></ORIG_TRAN_REF></SC_DETAIL>';

        SET REV_DETAIL='<REV_DETAIL><TRAN_SEQ_NO></TRAN_SEQ_NO><TRAN_DATE></TRAN_DATE></REV_DETAIL>';

        SET META_DATA='<META_DATA><META_COLUMNS/></META_DATA>';

    --  SET XML_REQ='<CBS_TRAN_IN>'||HEADER_IN||TRAN_DETAIL||DR_INFO||
    --  CR_INFO||SC_DETAIL||REV_DETAIL||META_DATA||'</CBS_TRAN_IN>';
        SET XML_REQ='<CBS_TRAN_IN>'||SC_DETAIL||REV_DETAIL||META_DATA||'</CBS_TRAN_IN>';

    --  CALL PROCESS_TRAN(XML_REQ,XML_RESP);

        IF(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(XML_RESP AFTER '<RESULT_CODE>') BEFORE '</RESULT_CODE>')='0') THEN
        UPDATE Database.{Schemas}.{Table} AS B SET B.TRANSACTION_STATUS='A' AND
        B.TRANSACTION_COUNT=2 WHERE B.STAN=ft_seq.STAN;
    ELSE
        UPDATE Database.{Schemas}.{Table} AS B SET B.TRANSACTION_COUNT=2 WHERE B.STAN=ft_seq.STAN;
    END IF;

    SET i=i+1;
END WHILE;
```

Comment: The error message tells you the line/column number: BIP2401E: (com.esql.code.UAE_FTProcess_Transaction.Main, **51.47**

Comment: @DanielSteinmann The line number 51.47 on module (com.esql.code.UAE_FTProcess_Transaction.Main is commented. Still it show same error multiple time after cleaning and redeploying. I am using IIB version 10 fix pack 20.

Comment: By the way my problem was solved after 4 hours as engaged on some other work. But at that time it deploy successfully without doing or changing anything in code. It strange to me. I think its bug in IIB version 10.